# Lenguaje Java boolean

Tags: java

Hola necesito ayuda con este programa actualmente estoy empezando y me gustaría que me ayudarán gracias de antemano
Mi problema es que al momento de correr el programa y al poner la palabra "true" me da "valores iguales" lo cual está bien pero al poner una palabra diferente como que da un tipo de error y no me pone "valores diferentes" que puedo hacer para que al momento de poner una palabra diferente a "true" me aparezca "valores diferentes" y gracias de nuevo por la ayuda [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qué bueno que estés empezando, te doy unos consejos. Es redundante escribir

```
Boolean trueValue = new Boolean(true);
```

Pues `true` es de tipo `boolean` (un tipo **primitivo**), mientras que `trueValue` es de tipo [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) (una **clase** que a su vez contiene, entre otras cosas, un tipo primitivo)

Luego [`Scanner+nextBoolean(): boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBoolean()) retorna ya un tipo `boolean` (**primitivo**), así que no hay necesidad de invocar al constructor de `Boolean` y crear un objeto.

Así que tampoco existe la necesidad de utilizar el método `equals` o alguno similiar, con el operador de comparación `==` es más que suficiente. **Nota**: Esto no siempre es así, a veces sí se requiere utilizar `equals` o un comparador, especialmente si trabajas con clases.

Ahora, si vemos el javadoc del método `Scanner+nextBoolean(): boolean` que dice que leerá el siguiente token del input y lo retornará a un valor booleano. En caso de que dicho token no pueda ser traducido a un valor booleano válido se lanzará una excepción InputMismatchException. **Nota**: Esta excepción NO es la única que puede lanzar ese método, pero es la más relevante en este contexto.

Y de hecho, si revisamos el código de Java (en mi caso revisé openjdk 11), el método se define algo similar a lo siguiente

```
public boolean nextBoolean()  {
    clearCaches();
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(next(boolPattern()));
}
```

De eso, lo importante es la llamada a `boolPattern()`, que se define de la siguiente manera

```
private static Pattern boolPattern() {
    Pattern bp = boolPattern;
    if (bp == null)
        boolPattern = bp = Pattern.compile(BOOLEAN_PATTERN,
                                      Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return bp;
}
```

Y `BOOLEAN_PATTERN` está declararado y definido como

```
private static final String BOOLEAN_PATTERN = "true|false";
```

Así que en pocas palabras, `boolPattern()` retorna un regex que va a hacer match con *true* o *false* sin tomar en cuenta mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Por último, el método `next()` es el invoca a otros métodos que realmente se encargan de hacer el match del regex obtenido con el el siguiente token existente en el buffer. Si lo que está en el buffer no hace match con el regex, simplemente se lanzará una excepción `InputMismatchException`.

Puedes leer el código de Java si quieres para conocer más detalles de cómo se hace eso, para descargarlo ve a https://openjdk.java.net/ o si usas GNU/Linux, probablemente lo puedas descargar del repositorio de tu distribución.

Entonces, en resumen

- No crear objetos innecesarios, e. g. `new Boolean(true)`
- El método `nextBoolean()` va a intentar hacer match del siguiente input en el buffer con el regex `true|false` y en caso de no encontrar coincidencias, lanzará una excepción `InputMismatchException`.

Para solucionar el "problema", hay que usar `try-catch` o alguna otra forma de parseo del input, personalmente lo haría así

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextBoolean() ?  "Yes!" : "No!");
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Formato no válido, sólo hay de dos: o es " + Boolean.TRUE.toString()
                   + " o es " + Boolean.FALSE.toString());
} catch (NoSuchElementException | IllegalStateException e) {
    System.err.println("Otras excepciones...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que el else (linea) no debe llevar condicional, es solamente else. Si quieres poner poner condicional en el caso que if no se cumpla, debes poner else if.

```
if (condicion) {
     //codigo si cumple la condicion
  }
else{
     //codigo cuando no se cumpla la condicion
   }
```